# Screenshots with Selenium Webdriver: How can I set the window size?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

As explained elsewhere ([Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)), you can take screenshots easily with PHPUnit using the Selenium Webdriver class PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase .

However, I cannot find a way to set the screen size of the generated screenshots. By default, their width seems to be limited to 1000 pixels.

BTW: the above mentioned Stackoverflow thread is closed. So I cannot post my question there.

Comment: I do not think this is possible.  I believe that the width and height are those of the website that you are browsing.  If a screenshot is not getting all of the webpage, then that is a different issue.  If you only want part of a webpage, then you have to crop it yourself.

Comment: The call of `$this->currentWindow()->size()` does affect the screenshot, but the size of the browser window itself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of resizing.  Glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much! This solves my problem. I post my code to provide a more complete example:

You can get any window with `$this->currentWindow()`and then call the "closure method" `size()` on it. I put that into my `setupPage()` method.

```
class DrupalWebtestBase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    /* ... */

    public function setUpPage()
    {       
        parent::setUpPage();

        if( $this->width && $this->height )
        {    
            // main window is named ''  
            $this->window('');

            // get window object
            $window = $this->currentWindow();

            // set window size
            $window->size( array(
                            'width'     => $this->width,
                            'height'    => $this->height) );
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshots taken later on reflect the set window dimensions above.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to resize your browser window? I found interesting post about it [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/selenium-screenshots-rendering). 
Some code snippet from there:

```
    $this->currentWindow()->size(array(
  'width' => 800,
  'height' => 600,
));
```